# how to prevent back button to login page after user logs in

Tags: authentication, back

i have a log in page where user enters username and password and then the user is redirected to his account page, but when i press the back button it takes me back to the log in page. How do i prevent that from happening.

Comment: Do you have some sample code?  What have you tried?  There is not enough information here to answer this question.

Comment: i am using auth component of cakephp, its a simple code of login checking and redirect

Answer (score 0):

You should add checking if user is logged in on login page. If yes, you should make redirection to default page.

Comment: there is checking, but its like the log in page is cached in the browser after login, and on click of back just display the cache page. Reloading of page does not happen when back button is pressed.

Comment: if when back button is clicked and i am on log in page and refresh the page it redirects me to the users account page

Comment: You can disable browser cashing for login page.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers

Comment: its already implemented, but still it takes you back to log in page

Answer (score 0):

In your controller (where you check if user is valid or not), make a session variable and initialise it to "connected" for example.

And in your login form check if your session variable is connected if so redirect to wanted page.